# Looking to replace the text in a file after match found in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have data in the below format in a .txt file:

`parameter1=12345 parameter2=23456 parameter3=23456` and so on.. the list is a long one.

I have found a way to match the `parameter1` and so on and replace it with some other number.

```
modified_file=File.read("modified_file.txt",)
modified_file=modified_file.to_s.sub(/#{parameter1}=/, "some text of your choice")
```

The above regular expression would only replace the value with `parameter1=` but I intend to change following `parameter1=`.

I want to write a regular expression which can match the data up to `=` and replace the data following that.

For Eg: I want to replace `12345` to `abcde` and `23456` to `xyzab` so the final result would be:

`parameter1=abcde parameter2=xyzab` and so on..

Comment: how about putting the patterns/replacements in a nice hash for us first and giving us a sample string.

Comment: The pattern is similar to the Example given above.
The text file contains a series of data 
I need to match the 1st part of the string upto "=" and change the data following "=" symbol. And look for the next data again. I hope this helps. I am hoping this could help, if not please let me know I will try to elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

`/(?<=parameter1=)\S+/`

What you want is called a "[lookbehind](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#label-Anchors)".

Comment: Thanks a lot :-) That works great for me ! And thank you for the link, now I can do more on regular expressions.